# Find polygons contained inside polygon using RGeo, PostGIS and ST_Contains

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgis, rgeo

I have two models: `Search` (geom saved on attribute `area`) and `Land` (geom saved on attribute `geom`).

`Land` is imported from an external service and is saved to DB with specific SRID. EG:

`SRID=28992;POLYGON((84078.122 444751.117,84076.78 444756.486,84074.578 444765.296,84073.017 444771.6,84072.863 444771.565,83990.385 444752.587,83983.081 444741.282,83973.47 444727.641,83977.639 444696.765,83977.795 444696.272,83978.017 444695.806,83978.303 444695.376,83978.645 444694.989,83979.038 444694.654,83979.474 444694.376,83979.944 444694.162,83980.439 444694.015,83980.849 444687.415,83980.059 444680.175,83981.009 444674.015,83990.579 444630.535,83991.039 444628.175,83992.959 444622.795,83993.499 444619.895,83996.899 444602.515,84008.879 444549.116,84012.229 444550.167,84008.676 444568.23,84006.244 444579.55,83996.923 444617.582,83994.764 444631.493,83990.631 444646.408,83982.258 444684.123,83981.276 444694.907,83977.284 444727.724,83982.965 444736.217,83992.091 444749.86,84017.353 444756.019,84019.237 444745.384,84019.439 444745.432,84064.525 444756.091,84065.019 444756.24,84065.528 444756.322,84066.044 444756.336,84066.557 444756.28,84067.058 444756.157,84067.539 444755.967,84067.989 444755.716,84068.402 444755.406,84068.77 444755.044,84069.086 444754.636,84069.345 444754.19,84069.542 444753.713,84069.674 444753.214,84070.354 444750.339,84070.689 444749.934,84071.073 444749.575,84071.5 444749.269,84071.963 444749.02,84072.455 444748.834,84072.966 444748.712,84073.489 444748.657,84074.014 444748.67,84074.533 444748.751,84075.038 444748.898,84083.199 444750.826,84082.865 444752.243,84078.122 444751.117))`

The geometry saved on a `Search` instance comes from coordinates on an OpenStreetMap, which I believe uses `SRID=4326`. In the DB I can see that these values are saved without the `SRID=` part. EG:

`POLYGON((4.270822 52.088838,4.271509 52.088324,4.271214 52.088232,4.270533 52.088235,4.270248 52.088637,4.270527 52.088822,4.270822 52.088838))`

```
class Land < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.in_area(area)
    sql = "SELECT * FROM #{self.table_name} WHERE ST_Contains(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(#{area},4326),4326), ST_Transform(geom,4326))"
    result = Land.connection.execute(sql)
  end
end
```

And I call it like so:

```rb
Land.in_area(Search.last.area)
```

Which gives the error:
`ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "52.19414")`

`Search.last.area.factory` returns a `RGeo::Geos::CAPIFactory`, with the wrong SRID. So I thought to make that a correct factory:

```rb
factory = RGeo::Geos.factory(srid: 4326).parse_wkt(Search.last.area)
Land.in_area(factory) # however, this still returns the same error
```

I’ve also tried a couple of other variations and combinations such as:

```rb
"SELECT * FROM #{self.table_name} WHERE ST_Contains(ST_Geomfromtext(#{area.to_s}), geom)"
```

Which all return the same error. I must be missing something very obvious. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you post a SQL trace of what happens when you run `Land.in_area(Search.last.area)`? Also you did you read back over all the documentation at https://github.com/rgeo/activerecord-postgis-adapter

Comment: Yes all those settings on acticerecord-postgis-adapter are present, and I've looked for similar-ish example (to no avail so far). Trace: https://gist.github.com/glennpjones/7b44ad7ece0f3026d97bdb2508fb7dfa

Comment: Ok, so the SQL string interpolation failed. If i embed the literal `POLYGON` string into the query, there is no syntax error anymore

Comment: I still don't understand why:  `SELECT * FROM lands WHERE ST_Contains(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText('POLYGON ((4.405174 52.046156, 4.461823 51.973884, 4.267502 51.962885, 4.267845 52.037287, 4.385948 52.054179, 4.405174 52.046156))'),4326),4326), ST_Transform(geom, 4326))` is OK but with string interpolation it throws a syntax error. Any idea why?

Comment: Nice glad you got it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved with a scope:

```
scope :in_area, -> (area_4326) { where("ST_Contains(ST_Transform(ST_SetSRID(ST_GeomFromText(?),4326),4326), ST_Transform(geom, 4326))", area_4326) }
```

Where `area_4326` is the string representation of the geometry